# In retrofit, how can I use Tag in the request as a parameter value without using Call?

Tags: android, annotations, retrofit2, okhttp, retrofit2.6

Retrofit: I want to use Tag annotation to pass some data in the request, and then I would like to intercept that data from the interceptor.

Something like [this](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Tag.html)

How can I use it something like this, but without using Call

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER,
        AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION
    )
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
    annotation class Tagz

@GET
suspend fun getUsers(@Tagz value: CachePolicy.Type, @Url placeholder: String): Response<UserEntity?>
```

Using the above is throwing me this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
```

**How can I pass my value in the parameter as a tag in the request?**

BTW: I was able to use tag like this

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
    annotation class CachePolicyTag(val value: CachePolicy.Type)

@GET
@CachePolicyTag(CachePolicy.Type.DefaultCache)
suspend fun getUsers(@Url placeholder: String): Response<UserEntity?>
```

But instead of an annotation function, I want it to pass as a parameter in this suspend function.

Comment: Tagz ? Are you sure you it is not Tag (wihtout Z) ?

Comment: yeah I was using my custom, now im using without the Z. I think im able to see the tag in my interceptor, just looking it now how to parse it.

Comment: request.tag(Invocation::class.java)?.let {
            cachePolicyType = it.arguments()[0] as CachePolicy.Type
        } I hope there is a better way to get that tag value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used retrofit @TAG to pass tag value and intercepted in the okhttp interceptor.

```
@GET
suspend fun getUsers(@Tag cacheType: CachePolicy.Type, @Url placeholder: String): Response<UserEntity?>
```

and in my Okhttp interceptor

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request =  chain.request() 
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        request.tag(Invocation::class.java)?.let {
                kotlin.runCatching {
                   val cachePolicyType = it.arguments()[0] as CachePolicy.Type
                } 
        }
        return response
}
```

In case of any errors or class cast exception, it won't throw any exception out side of the runCatching block as well.

Comment: Try `request.tag(CachePolicy.Type::class.java)` to get the tagged parameter directly.

Comment: it says: Type mismatch.
Required:
Class<out TypeVariable(T)>
Found:
KClass<CachePolicy.Type>